# HDMI & VGA issues with MacBook Pro Retina & Acer Monitor

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi, dvi, vga

I'm having a very strange issue.
I inherited an Acer monitor from a friend that is full HD, 1080p. Good monitor overall. When connecting ONLY an HDMI cable from my Mac to the monitor, I get no signal. But if I connect both an HDMI and a VGA (via Thunderbolt adapter) to the Acer, I'm then able to toggle between inputs, and the HDMI input works fine. Problem is, now I have a useless Thunderbolt cable taking up one of my inputs. Any ideas?

MacBook Pro 15" Retina 2013

Yosemite 10.10.4

NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB

Acer S240hl monitor

Comment: Does the HDMI still work if you try unplugging the VGA while leaving the HDMI plugged in?

Comment: Also, try **Detect Displays** button in the **Display pane of Displays preferences**

Comment: No, once I unplug the VGA cable, the monitor goes black. Since it's a computer monitor and not a TV, I'm unable to cycle between inputs when it's black.

Comment: Ah, I forgot, you have to hold the option key in order to see some of the extra features. Well, hitting Detect Displays did not help any. If I just had a third Thunderbolt port I wouldn't even care...

Comment: FWIW, I have another HDTV that I used to use as a monitor before getting this Acer. It's a 19" Dynex. That used to be fine using HDMI from my old MacBook Pro, a 13" from 2009. If I try to use HDMI with my new 15" Mac, the same thing happens. No love from the HDMI slot... While VGA works perfectly fine. This leads me to believe it's something from the Mac, and not from the monitor.

Comment: I'm currently running an ROC 2462w via HDMI out on my MacBook Pro Retina 13" Late 2013 model.  It works fine but at time takes a while to 'wake up' when Mac wakes up.  You may have to get the HDMI port checked out by Apple.

Comment: Here's another update.... I left the HDMI plugged in and opened a program. The program window opened on the external monitor, even though it was black and I could not see anything. So obviously the Mac is recognizing that it's plugged into something. Why it isn't showing up on the monitor is strange

Comment: @Cody: Did you find the solution for your problem? I am facing the same issue. It would be great if you could post the solution.